# Artifacts missing after version upgrade to 2.14

Tags: maven, nexus

I want to upgrade my nexus repo from 2.10.0-02 to latest 3.x edition.

So I followed the [documentation](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/upgrade-compatibility---repository-manager-2-to-3) which states I should first upgrade it to latest 2.y edition (which is nexus-2.14.13-01).

I followed the steps as mentioned in the documentation, viz.

1. Stop old version nexus server.
2. Extract nexus-2.14.13-01.zip at same location as previous nexus, so '*sonatype-work*' becomes the sibling directory.
3. Point soft links and env variables to new nexus.
4. Start new nexus server.
5. Change owner to nexus user. (as in previous version)

But in my new nexus-2.14.13-01 instance, I cannot see my personal artifacts, be it proxy or hosted.
Although I can still see all my artifacts in `/sonatype-work/nexus/storage` folder.

What am I missing? Please suggest

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to regenerate indices?

Comment: @JFMeier I've executed a repair index task. Is it same as regenerating?

Comment: There are different options. Did it help?

Comment: @JFMeier, nope.

Answer (score 0):

The browse storage UI in Nexus Repo 2.x displays what is on disk. It's as simple as that.  So if the artifacts are not visible it means the work directory is not set to the right location.  Edit $installdir/conf/nexus.properties and set "nexus-work=/sonaytype-work/nexus".